# Is it possible to evaluate routes before passing them to another template?

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a template that reads through `jQuery` an json array from backend, and populates a select html element.

I had it previously like this (unnecessary code ommited):

```
....   
<select class="mySelect"></select>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
     url: "@routes.Users.list",
     success: function(data) {
        // Populate the select from 'data' array
     }
   });
<script> 
....
```

Now, I've rewritten this part into a separate template, and I need to provide the same `route url`:

```
@_customSelect(..., "@routes.Users.list"...)
```

However, the route is not evaluated, with or without `@` (yeah, there's a 'magic character' at the start of the line). I get HTTP errors 404 (the address cannot be found, obviously `http://localhost:9000/@routes.Users.list` does not exist).

Is this kind of mechanism possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need that first `@` "magic character". The template engine is smart enough to figure out the end of the statement.

```
@_customSelect(..., routes.Users.list, ...)
```

The `routes.Users.list` is an instance of `play.api.mvc.Call`. If you need it as a `String` or something (due to the type-safe-ness) then I think you can add `.url` or `.toString` at the end.

```
@_customSelect(..., routes.Users.list.url, ...)
```

Comment: It worked :). Thanks man! For assets, I had to use toString, but routes worked with `url`